# Create an AWS RDS instance without NAT Gateway using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

Is it possible to create a [serverless RDS cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.ServerlessCluster.html)  via CDK without NAT Gateway? The NAT Gateway base charge is pretty expensive for a development environment. I'm also not interested in setting up a NAT instance. I'm attaching a Lambda in the VPC with the RDS instance [like this](https://serverlessfirst.com/lambda-vpc-internet-access-no-nat-gateway/).

```js
    // VPC
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'MyVPC');

    // RDS
    const dbCluster = new rds.ServerlessCluster(this, 'MyAuroraCluster', {
      engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_MYSQL,
      defaultDatabaseName: 'DbName',
      vpc,
    });
```

Comment: 1. [vpcPlacement](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/b8f48e514c09d2f46d8bbae27171877df61e7f2a/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/instance.ts#L323-L329) is marked as deprecated with a recommendation to use vpcSubnets.

2. Does the stack that gets created include a NAT Gateway?

3. The post you linked doesn't require a NAT Gateway. If you create the Serverless Cluster in a private subnet, like in the post, does one get created?

4. Could you use the [Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-rds-readme.html#data-api)?

Comment: This does create a NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. You may have to add some VPC endpoints like Secrets Manager so password rotation can be done, but it is possible. You will need to create a VPC with subnets that have no NAT gateway too.

```js
// VPC
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'MyVPC', {
  natGateways: 0,
  subnetConfiguration: [
    {
      cidrMask: 24,
      name: 'public',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 28,
      name: 'rds',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
    }
  ]
});
// RDS
const dbCluster = new rds.ServerlessCluster(this, 'MyAuroraCluster', {
  engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_MYSQL,
  defaultDatabaseName: 'DbName',
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
  },
  vpc,
});
```

If you want Secrets Manager controlled password, use:

```js
vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('SecretsManagerEndpoint', {
  service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.SECRETS_MANAGER,
});
dbCluster.addRotationSingleUser();
```

EDIT NOTE: At some point, the CDK Enums were updated from `PRIVATE` to `PRIVATE_ISOLATED`

Answer (score 0):

Serverless clusters cannot be placed into a public subnet.

This is a hard and documented limitation of RDS Serverless.

Comment: I don't need internet access to the cluster.